# Placing a function statement within an if statement

Tags: javascript

I've heard it claimed that putting a function statement within an if statement is bad practice within the context of JavaScript.  Why is this so?

Comment: Note that putting a function declaration of the form `someVariable = function() { }` (which isn't a function statement) within an if block is OK. (In which case `someVariable` should be declared somewhere before the if statement.)

Comment: Show a code example please.

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree with you although typically the scenario you described is not called a function declaration. Instead, its generally referred to as creating function expressions.

Comment: @wmock - True. Actually the word I meant to use is "definition" (but I can't edit that comment now). The function is *defined* by a *function expression* as you say, and then (in my example) assigned to a variable that is *declared* earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bad practice because function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the lexical scope **REGARDLESS** of whether your code enters that part of the `if` statement.

For example:

```
var someFunction = function () {
  var num = 5;

  if ( num !== 5 ) {
     function anotherFunction () {
       console.log( 'hello there' );
     }
  }

  anotherFunction();
};

someFunction(); // logs out 'hello there'
```

Even though `anotherFunction` was **seemingly** declared within the `if` statement, this doesn't matter to the JavaScript engine because all function declarations are hoisted to the top of the lexical scope (in this case, to the top of the lexical scope for the `someFunction` function). This is why it is possible to invoke `anotherFunction` outside of the `if` statement.

It gets even more troublesome in the following scenario:

```
var someFunction = function () {
  var num = 5;

  if ( num === 5 ) {
     function anotherFunction () {
       console.log( 'hello there' );
     }
  } else {
     function anotherFunction () {
       console.log( 'bye bye' );
     }
  }

  anotherFunction();
};

someFunction(); // logs out 'bye bye'
```

You'd **expect** the result to be 'hello world' but the reason this second scenario logs 'bye bye' is because the JavaScript engine hoists ALL function declarations to the top of the lexical scope. When it hoists the first function declaration, the identifier 'anotherFunction' references the function object with 'hello there'. However, when it hoists the second function declaration, it is simply assigning another function object (the one with 'bye bye') to the existing identifier `anotherFunction`.

You can see how misleading and confusing this is because it goes against your expectations.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.  Thanks.  I was under the impression that the only thing being hoisted was a variable with the name of the function with the value "undefined", and that the actual function body wasn't assigned to that name until later.  But -- if I'm understanding you correctly -- it's the entire function statement that is being hoisted.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted entirely (the actual function object as well as the identifier). Variable declarations are hoisted up with just the identifier along with the value `undefined`.